# How to change the surrounding color of a selected slider handle in ant-design?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, antd

[image: slider handle]

This is the codesandbox with some attempts to change that
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4102-forked-jn0si?file=/index.css

I managed to change all other colors, but the blue color surrounding the circular handle cannot be changed, can any one give some help? Thank you very much !

Comment: You should add some code. I'm guessing you can try assigning `outline: none` to the handle class.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a code sandbox for this, tried `outline: none` but does not work. I believe this must be related to `antd-wave-shadow-color`, still trying...

Comment: tried `box-shadow` and worked

Comment: That's great!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtrl1.png)

For anyone who has the same problem, please try `box-shadow`

For example,
`box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px  fade(rgb(122, 122, 122),12%);`